# What is your ratio Bug fixing vs Enhancements?

Tags: maintenance-plan

In the spirit of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743442/implementing-features-vs-bug-fixing) I wanted to have a sense of what is the proportion of time split between fixing bugs and implementing new features.  If possible try to give an estimate for the product as a whole as opposed to individual developer stats and try to make an average over the course of a typical year.  Do provide a general descriptive of the product/project to allow comparison.  Specifically :

- Maturity of project
- Is it still actively developed or strictly in maintenance ?
- Size estimate of the product/project
- Size of team developing it (all inclusive)
- What is your team score on the [Joel test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html).

Ex :

- approx 80% time spent bug fixes 20% new stuff
- Mature software (20 years old)
- Actively developed
- 1.5M Line of Text, approx 700k - 900k LOC
- 12-15 actively coding in it.
- we got 5/12 for sure, some would say 7/12.

Answer (score 3):

I would estimate:
New features 70%, Bugs 10%, Technical debt (refactoring etc.) 20%

- Maturity: 2 years
- Actively developed
- Team size: 8
- LOC: 50k-100k
- Joel Test: 9/12

You didn't ask for technology stack but if you are interested it's Ruby on Rails

Comment: This is almost the same as my current project. Differences are Joel test is lower, its asp.net/c#, and lower team size.

Answer (score 3):

I'd estimate we spend around 70% of our time on new features and 30% on Bugs.

- Maturity 10 years
- Actively developed
- Team size 14 (1 manager, 1 tester, 1 UI designer, 11 developers (8 on new features and 3 dedicated to maintenance))
- 2.2M lines of text (950K actual code)
- Joel Test 10/12

Comment: Great thanks...  May not be significant statistically but there seems to be a correlation between the Joel Test and the ratio.  Although I am not surprised by this find it is nice to see data going this way.

Comment: An interesting observation regarding the Joel Test.  We certainly didn't start out on this development with a 10 score (it was more like a 5), but we added the others over time which has helped with the ratio.  Another thing to note is that our ratio has also changed over time.  About 2 years ago we spent approx 50% of our time on Bugs before splitting the team and really trying to focus on new development.

Answer (score 2):

- 50% debugging, 50% new code (and personally I want the debugging part to be lower)
- Software is 15 years old
- 1.5M line of text (with 170K empty lines, 250K lines of comment, 800K lines of actual code)
- about 10 people developing on it
- Joel Test: 8/12

Comment: sounds like we are in a similar situation.  What you think is the primary reason you spend so much time on bug fixing and what could you do to reduce this figure ?

Comment: Problems: Some parts of the software have become too complex.  Software is too flexible (allows too many configurations) so we can never foresee all possible configuration combinations.  
Solutions: Better scope determination.  Keep things simple.  Test sooner.  Automated testing.  Make sure developers can focus on their task.  Make people responsible for the quality.

Comment: yes... this sounds familiar...  The software slowly becoming a platform to do everything but end up not doing anything right without copious amount of scripting in a proprietary scripting language, that, in itself is also becoming a platform...  yikes

Answer (score 0):

From our time tracking software I see our teams feature/defect ratio of last year is:

- 75% feature tasks
- 25% defect tasks

Other stats:

- Software is ~10 years old
- 4M lines of text
- Currently 11 developers
- Joel Test: 7/12

Answer (score 0):

- 50% New features, 25% bug fixing, 25% testing
- Actively developed
- 9M lines of text
- around 25
- 9/12

We're developing a game (c++) using our own framework and engine, so it is actively developed. The stats above are rounded up from our tracking software, however I could make a note here that while developing minor bugs are already resolved without creating a bug listing for it.